# Spring security login form resubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-security

I have implemented spring security prevent concurrent login using session registry implementation every thing working fine.

But the issue is with Browser close.
Since 100% browser close event is not there in javascript and jquery i dont have any option to invalide sessio.

Please some one suggest how to invalid session on browser close.Its should not effect page refresh,on submmit,on click,going away from navigatio.

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping the session through cookies? Otherwise, you won't need to invalidate the session when the browser changes, as the new session will have a new id.